# Need development code for xml-apis 1.4.01

Tags: xml, maven, xerces, build.xml

I want the **source code jar of xml-apis 1.4.01** to build the jar myself in my local. I have checked on maven https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01 but the source code there doesn't have the files needed to build the jar. So **I need the source code jar which contains the build.xml etc. kind of files.** Can anyone tell me where can I find this ?

Comment: Is this is what you need: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01

Comment: No. The source code jar present on maven doesn't contain build.xml related files so i can't re-build the xml-apis jar in my local without them.

Comment: are you looking for something like this? http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/xml-commons/trunk/java/external/ You would need SVN, i think. Not sure if there is a neat tarball of the xml-commons project

Comment: @govi Can you confirm what is the version of source code that you shared. And what java version and build environment is required to build it ?

Comment: umm.. eclipse classpath looks at a 1.3 container, http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/xml-commons/trunk/java/external/.classpath and the version is 1.4.02 according to the build xml http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/xml-commons/trunk/java/external/build.xml

Comment: i suspect that it might be a valid eclipse project, worth importing into your IDE. I still do not understand why you would want to compile from source... but i do think that the repo is all set for primetime.